# NDSolveValue order of calculation

Tags: differential-equations

There is an error for this code as you can see.

```
c = 4;
u = 2;
Array[T, u];
v = Compile[{}, Sin[Y]];

Do[n = 1;
  If[j == 1,
   T[j] = 
     AbsoluteTiming[
      While[n <= c, 
        h[j, n] = 
         NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == Cos[y[x]]*1.0, y'[0] == 2.606, 
           y[0] == (n - 1)/c*2*Pi - Pi}, y, {x, 0, 1}, 
          "Method" -> {"EquationSimplification" -> {Automatic, 
              "TimeConstraint" -> Infinity}}, AccuracyGoal -> 3]; 
        n++];];
        ,
   T[j] = 
     AbsoluteTiming[
      While[n <= c, 
        h[j, n] = 
         NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == 
            Cos[y[x]] + Sum[Block[{Y = h[1, i][x]}, v[]], {i, 1, c}]
           , y'[0] == 2.606, y[0] == (n - 1)/c*2*Pi - Pi}, 
          y, {x, 0, 1}, 
          "Method" -> {"EquationSimplification" -> {Automatic, 
              "TimeConstraint" -> Infinity}}, AccuracyGoal -> 3.];
        n++];];
   ];, {j, u}];


CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression <<1>> should be a machine-size real number. >>

CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
```

But when I change the argument of `h[1,i]` to a number e.g., `1.0`, it runs well. I think the `x` is not a fixed value within the NDSolveValue, so that is the origin of the error. So I think if I calculate `h[1,i][x]` first at every `x`, before putting that coefficient into the differential equation, it should work. So tried using `Activate, With, Block, Evaluate, Module`. But none of them worked. Would be there a way so that I can circumvent this error?

Comment: Why not just use `Sin[h[1, 1][x]]`? Compiling `Sin` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: This was just a simplified version of the issue. The function I want to use is a lot more complex. That is the reason why I want to use Compile rather than a function.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You are right about the basic issue: `NDSolve`, like most Mathematica functions, evaluates its arguments first, which means that `x` does not have a numeric value. The standard solution is to define a helper function using the `x_?NumericQ` argument test, so it won't evaluate for non-numerical `x`.

Comment: Another way would be to define `v = Compile[{Y}, Sin[Y], 
   "RuntimeOptions" -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False];` and then use `v[h[1, i][x]]` in your equation instead of that `Block`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But if I use `v[h[1, i][x]-h[1,n][x]]` in the equation, it does not work. I think it should work too...

Comment: I think the messages are harmless, but you can use `vv[arg_?NumericQ] := v[arg]` instead of `v` to avoid them.

Comment: I see.. If I increase `c` to a few thousand, the computation time increase significantly. Would there be some way to reduce to computation time? I tried `ParallelSum`, but it increased the time. And when I change the most outer `Do` to `ParallelDo`, the code did not run. I am running on a server of 24 cores.